# Can't run embeded Tomcat with spring-boot-parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, logging

in my application I try to run spring boot app in a standard way. I have three modules

```
parent-module (spring-boot-parent 2.2.6, packaging:pom)
|-child-api (parent-module is parent)
|-child-service (parent-module is parent)
```

First I had some problems with conflicts between slf4j and logback so I decided to exclude logback from classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then I lost all the logs so I decided to add something like this line to application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=DEBUG
```

Now when I try to run my app all I've got is:

```
C:\jdk-11\bin\java.exe -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63394:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\rybak_b\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file967796595 PermissionsServiceApplication
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol port=8082)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol bindOnInit=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint bindOnInit=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol maxPostSize=2097152)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint maxPostSize=2097152)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol parseBodyMethods=POST)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint parseBodyMethods=POST)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesRmiTargets=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopThreads=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopTimerThreads=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread=true)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreadLocals=false)
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
mar 07, 2022 7:57:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Embeded Tomcat just stops immediately after start and I don't know why. I am using JDK 11, spring boot-parent 2.2.6-RELESE or 2.6.3 (same problem).

When I added `logging.level.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG` there are a few logs more:

```
 mar 07, 2022 8:10:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol port=8082)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol bindOnInit=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint bindOnInit=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol maxPostSize=2097152)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint maxPostSize=2097152)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
FINE: Add child StandardHost[localhost] StandardEngine[Tomcat]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
FINE: Add child StandardWrapper[default] TomcatEmbeddedContext[]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
FINE: Add child TomcatEmbeddedContext[] StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol parseBodyMethods=POST)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint parseBodyMethods=POST)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
FINE: Starting ROOT
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
FINE: Configuring default Resources
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
FINE: Processing standard container startup
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader startInternal
FINE: Starting this Loader
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesRmiTargets=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopThreads=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopTimerThreads=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread=true)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils setProperty
FINE: IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreadLocals=false)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase startInternal
FINE: No SingleSignOn Valve is present
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
FINE: No manager found. Checking if cluster manager should be used. Cluster configured: [false], Application distributable: [false]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
FINE: Configured a manager of class [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
FINE: Add child StandardWrapper[dispatcherServlet] StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE: Configuring application event listeners
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE:  Configuring event listener class 'org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE: Sending application start events
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: Start: Loading persisted sessions
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: Loading persisted sessions from [SESSIONS.ser]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: No persisted data file found
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE: Starting filters
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE:  Starting filter 'requestContextFilter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE:  Starting filter 'Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE:  Starting filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE:  Starting filter 'formContentFilter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
FINE: Starting completed
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper addHost
FINE: Registered host [localhost]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener registerContext
FINE: Register Wrapper [default] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener registerContext
FINE: Register Wrapper [dispatcherServlet] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener registerContext
FINE: Register Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener registerHost
FINE: Register host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener unregisterHost
FINE: Unregister host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener unregisterContext
FINE: Unregister Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener unregisterWrapper
FINE: Unregister Wrapper [default] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener unregisterWrapper
FINE: Unregister Wrapper [dispatcherServlet] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE: Stopping filters
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE:  Stopping filter 'requestContextFilter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig unregisterJMX
FINE: JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter] and name [requestContextFilter]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE:  Stopping filter 'Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig unregisterJMX
FINE: JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter] and name [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE:  Stopping filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig unregisterJMX
FINE: JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter] and name [characterEncodingFilter]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE:  Stopping filter 'formContentFilter'
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig unregisterJMX
FINE: JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter] and name [formContentFilter]
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stopInternal
FINE: Stopping
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
FINE: Unloading persisted sessions
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
FINE: No persisted sessions to unload
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
FINE: Sending application stop events
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stopInternal
FINE: Processing standard container shutdown
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader stopInternal
FINE: Stopping this Loader
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase getResourceAsStream
FINE: getResourceAsStream(org/apache/catalina/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention.class)
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase getResourceAsStream
FINE:   Delegating to parent classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6ed3ef1
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase getResourceAsStream
FINE:   --> Returning stream from parent
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resetContext
FINE: resetContext Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
mar 07, 2022 8:10:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stopInternal
FINE: Stopping complete

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Edit:

Sometimes I've got this error:

```
mar 07, 2022 11:12:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre16Compat <clinit>
FINE: Class not found so assuming code is running on a pre-Java 16 JVM
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.net.UnixDomainSocketAddress
```

Comment: have you tried different OS/JDK/computer? I have had some success in troubleshooting by changing one of those

Comment: Remove the exclusions, you now have log4j which isn't really advisable. Remove the version for liquibase and provide your dependencies in your pom.

Comment: @M.Deinum remove version of liquibase didn't help. But I edited a question, somethimes there is error: Class not found so assuming code is running on a pre-Java 16, java.net.UnixDomainSocketAddress but I don't know from where it coming from.

Comment: That is just an info message and isn't relevant. I requested you add all your dependencies as the culprit is probably in there (conflicting dependencies etc.).